# Dynamically change inline style value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change an inline style value dynamically using jquery.

My html code:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="margin-bottom:1px;">
    <div id="progress_bar" class="bar bar-success" style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying dynamically increase the width of the progress bar with a variable let's say **var amount**:

```
style="width: var amount"
```

Could someone help me out a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `.animate` ... See below:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c78vF/151/)

```
$("#but").click(function(){ 
    var yourValue = "50%"
      $('.progressbar').animate({ width: yourValue }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.css()` to get/set css style value:

```
$('#progress_bar').css('width' , 'value_here');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .addClass and .removeClass to add and remove CSS class respectively.

```
$( "progress_bar" ).addClass( "classWithNewCSS" );

$( "progress_bar" ).removeClass( "classWithNewCSS" );
```

thus, in real time, it adds and removes this CSS, applying the respective changes.

Answer (score 0):

More info on the .CSS method.
http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$('#progress_bar').css({
   'background-color':'#FFF',
   'width': variable
});
```